# Proving integral $\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \cdot n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, summation

Show that the following equality is true.
$$
\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}\, \mathrm dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \cdot n!}
$$

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Where can the sum com from ?

Comment: Does it have something to do with $e^x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ where x would equal to 1?

Comment: Just substitute your development in the integral, and exchange $\int$ and $\sum$, using the proper theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integral is not "improper" in the sense that $\frac{e^x-1}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}1$.

As you noted, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, so 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^x-1}{x} {\rm d}x = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}{\rm d}x $$
The convergence under the sum is normal (this you have to prove, and cite the theorem), hence uniform, so you can switch the sum terms :
$$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}{\rm d}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}{\rm d}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{x^n}{n\cdot n!}\right]_0^1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$$

Comment: $\frac{e^x - 1}{x} = \frac{1}{x} \cdot (e^x - 1) = \frac{1}{x} \cdot (1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots -1) =  \frac{1}{x} \cdot (\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots) = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$ - that is what I was missing! And since series of $e^x$ converges for all $x \in R$ we can swap integral with series symbol.

Comment: It is not sufficient to say that the series of $e^x$ converges : the convergence has to be uniform on $[0,1]$ (or you have to use some theorem of dominated convergence).

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}dx$$
Now note that:
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+...$$
So we can say that:
$$e^x-1=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+...=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Now we just divide by $x$:
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
Which now simplifies our integral to:
$$I=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}dx$$
Now interchange the integral and summation:
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{x^n}{n.n!}\right]_0^1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n.n!}\approx 1.32$$